# How to retrieve the date of the working days in a php array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can someone help me, where should I put my $days[] array so that holidays are not included in this array.

My code is as follows

```
$data['ferie'] = $this->CalendrierModel->find('ferie');
$timestamp = strtotime ('2020-05-18');
$days      = array();
$i         = 0;
$jourOuvre = 5;

foreach($data['ferie'] as $row){
  $ferie = array($row->start);

  while($i < $jourOuvre){
    $date_tmp = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i . 'weekdays', $timestamp));
    if (in_array($date_tmp , $ferie)){
      $jourOuvre++;
      $date_tmp = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+1days', $date_tmp));
    }
    $days[] = $date_tmp;
    $i++;
  }
}
var_dump($days);
```

this code makes :

```
699:
array (size=5)
  0 => string '2020-05-18' (length=10)
  1 => string '2020-05-19' (length=10)
  2 => string '2020-05-20' (length=10)
  3 => string '2020-05-21' (length=10)
  4 => string '2020-05-22' (length=10)
```

while **2020-05-21 is a holiday**.

**NB:** $data['ferie'] is an array of holidays.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `$ferie = array($row->start)`, you seem to only check if the date is in the 1 holiday at a time.

Comment: `$ferie = array($row->start)` is an array that contains all the holidays from my database.

Comment: No, it is not, it contains _one_ item, the _current_ one from `$data['ferie']`, wrapped into an additional array.

Comment: Oh, okay, I get it... thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, guys. I did it.

```
$data['ferie'] = $this->CalendrierModel->find('ferie');

$timestamp = strtotime ('2020-05-18');
$days  = array();
$ferie = array();
$i     = 0;
$jourOuvre = 5;

foreach($data['ferie'] as $row){
  $ferie[] = $row->start;
}

while($i < $jourOuvre){
  $date_tmp = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i . ' weekdays' , $timestamp));

  if(in_array($date_tmp , $ferie)) {
    $jourOuvre++;
  } else {
    $days[] = $date_tmp;
  }
  $i++;
}
var_dump($days);
```

Holidays are out of my array :

```
C:\wamp\www\HELPJUR\application\controllers\Ticket.php:816:
array (size=5)
  0 => string '2020-05-18' (length=10)
  1 => string '2020-05-19' (length=10)
  2 => string '2020-05-20' (length=10)
  3 => string '2020-05-22' (length=10)
  4 => string '2020-05-25' (length=10)
```

Comment: Please accept this answer if you've solved your problem.